# Save and retrieve chats in Bot framework composer

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am creating a chatbot using Bot framework composer. My Chatbot contains different dialogues and in each dialogue I have different set of Questions and their Answer according to my domain. Further more, I am using directline channel to communicate with my chatbot using mobile application. The userId has been set in GenerateToken api and StartConversation api and I am able to receive and send activites.
Now what I want is, I am in Question 3 of Dialog A and user closes the mobile application, I want to start the bot conversation exactly from Question 3 of Dialog A. How can I do that?

I have tried cosmos Db along with Bot framework Composer, it is only storing dialog states and user state but it is not retrieving it.